# Angular 2 update deployment process using Firebase console

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-console

I have created a simple application in angular 2 and successfully deployed the application using firebase console following the steps below:

Do Create a project with Angular CLI first. Get More info here https://cli.angular.io/

```
Step 1: Build your App
```

Run the below cmd to build

ng build --prod

```
Step 2: Create FireBase project and Install Firebase CLI
```

Open the Firebase console at https://console.firebase.google.com/ and create a new Firebase project.

To install the Firebase command line tools run:

npm install -g firebase-tools

```
Step 3: Deploy to FireBase
```

Run the below firebase cmd to login:

firebase login
It will open the browser and ask you for authentication. Login with your Firebase account. There after you can close the browser window. On the command line you'll receive the message that the login has been performed successfully.

Now run the below cmd:

firebase init
First of all you're being asked which of the Firebase client features you want to use. You should select the option Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting site. Next the Firebase client will ask which folder to use for deployment. Type in dist. That is important because that is the location where our production build is stored.

Next the question is ask if this app is a single page app and if it should rewrite all URLs to index.html. In our case we need to answer yes.

Last question is if Firebase should over write file index.html. The answer to that question is no.

Now, Run the below cmd to deploy:

firebase deploy
Firebase will provide a URL which you can use to access your application online.

**"But if I again update my application,how can I reflect those changes in to my deployed project?
Should follow the deployment process again for my updated application or is there any way out to update the changes directly into the deployed application.**

Comment: what about `ng build` then `firebase deploy` command?

Comment: thanks for your reply .. i tried doing this but the changes are not being reflected in my deployed application.

Comment: I was using those commands, and they worked in firefox but not in chrome. If you are using chrome, maybe you should clear the caches or test it in incognito mode.

Comment: ok i will try this out

Comment: yes this is working .. thanks a lot. i checked using firefox